# apply margins in ul of child elements for parent elements

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I would like to apply the margins of child li for the parent li elements as well.
With this code, the submenu of "Projekte" is crossing the borders of "Kontakt" below.
Thank you for helping in advance!

```css
#hide {
  display: none;
}

#projekte:hover #hide {
  display: block;
}

li {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

a {
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Navigationsmen&uuml;</h1>
<br />
<br />
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
  <li id="projekte">
    <a href="projektuebersicht.html">Projekte</a>
    <ul id="hide">
      <li><a href="projekt1.html">Projekt 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="projekt2.html">Projekt 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="mailto:">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add position parameters to `#projekte:hover #hide`: `position: relative` to be able to create an offset and according `top` and `left` values:

```css
#hide {
  display: none;
}

#projekte:hover #hide {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 60px;
  top: -230%;
}

li {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

a {
  color: grey;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>Navigationsmen&uuml;</h1>
<br />
<br />
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
  <li id="projekte">
    <a href="projektuebersicht.html">Projekte</a>
    <ul id="hide">
      <li><a href="projekt1.html">Projekt 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="projekt2.html">Projekt 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="mailto:">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is even better!

Answer (score 0):

the trick here is to add margin for  `#projekte:hover #hide li`  element

```
<body>
    <h1>Navigationsmen&uuml;</h1>
    <br />
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li id="projekte">
            <a href="projektuebersicht.html">Projekte</a>
            <ul id="hide">
            <li><a href="projekt1.html">Projekt 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="projekt2.html">Projekt 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="mailto:">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>       
</body>
```

```
#hide {display: none;
            
            
    }
    #projekte:hover #hide {display: block;}
    li {width: 80px;
        height: 30px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        margin-top: 50px;
        
    }
    a {color: grey;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul {list-style-type: none;
    }
    a:hover {color:blue;}
    
    #projekte:hover #hide li {
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much!